# What is the difference between using XSLT <xsl:element> and declaring elements literally?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have started using XSLT just recently and am wondering what the effective difference is between using `<xsl:element>` for defining elements vs. just declaring them as literals in the XSLT. For example, lets take a simplified case where I'm converting the contents of a tiny XML document into (x)HTML.

**1.I could go with the `<xsl:element>` way:**

```
<xsl:element name="h1">
    <xsl:value-of select="heading"/>
</xsl:element>
```

**2. Or define the element by hand:**

```
<h1>
    <xsl:value-of select="heading"/>
</h1>
```

What is the actual difference between these two and if a difference exists, which of them is considered *'good-style'*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're almost identical, the exception being that a literal `<h1>` element will add to the result tree the namespace nodes that are in scope at that point in the *stylesheet*, whereas the `<xsl:element name="h1">` won't.  What difference this makes to your output depends on exactly what namespace declarations your stylesheet includes and where in the result tree you make use of them, if at all.  For example, run against any input XML document the following transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:foo="http://example.com">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <foo:element1 />
      <foo:element2 />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output (using xsltproc):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:foo="http://example.com">
  <foo:element1/>
  <foo:element2/>
</root>
```

but changing the literal `<root>` in the stylesheet to `<xsl:element name="root">` instead produces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo:element1 xmlns:foo="http://example.com"/>
  <foo:element2 xmlns:foo="http://example.com"/>
</root>
```

as the `<xsl:element>` form doesn't attach the "foo" namespace node to the generated element.  If this matters, and you actually want to copy the stylesheet namespace declarations onto an element you create with `<xsl:element>` you can do so by nesting something like

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::foo" />
```

directly inside it (using the idiom of `document('')` which provides access to the stylesheet XML document itself).

But generally, the main use of `<xsl:element>` is when the element name is calculated rather than a "compile-time" literal.

Answer (score 5):

xsl:element allows defining elements whose name you don't know when writing the stylesheet and also element whose names are dynamically created. I would always use the inline definition (i.e. by hand) if possible. It is shorter and I consider it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

One other technical difference not yet noted in the answers:  if you restrict yourself to the `xsl:element` constructor, your stylesheet can be valid against the DTD for XSLT.  In some environments (where you have a DTD-aware editor, for example) that can be advantageous.  That said, I have been told many times that no one actually uses a DTD to guide their XSLT construction (except me, that is).

There is also a metaphysical difference (literal result elements can be viewed as a form of tag abuse, because you're using an `h1` where the meaning is *not* "this is a first-level heading" but instead "put a first-level heading here"), but this is of interest primarily to markup theorists and language designers; I mention it only for completeness' sake.

Comment: Ah, that is a nice caveat indeed. Although I believe you are right about the DTD not being used a lot (I know i don't), it is still intrestng to find out about subtle differences like this. One might not utilize DTDs, but that doesn't mean the next project he/she is on won't.

Answer (score 1):

**I would strongly advise using literal result elements everywhere this is possible**.

Therefore, if the name of the element is known in advance (not determined dynamically) and there are no namespace manipulations required, then use a literal-result element.

**The major advantage of using a literal-result element is its readability and less moving parts than compared with `xsl:element` -- which means less error-prone**.

Comment: @michael.hor257k why did you rollback my edit? Did you not read the reason?

Comment: @Stijn Two people did not not consider your reason a valid one.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Who's the second person? Imho putting half the answer in bold text is just a way to attract attention to the answer, it's not used to put emphasis on something.

Comment: "*Who's the second person?*" Why, the original author, of course. Whose reputation is 6 times yours and mine put together, so I doubt he needs to "attract attention" to his answers. The validity of a formatting choice is measured semantically, not statistically, You may disagree with the choice, but it's not your post and not your decision to make.

Comment: @Stijn, I have some practice in writing training materials and the "bold" here has a proven educational effect -- no need to attract anyone's attention to myself ...